# Counting number of roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to find an upper bound for number of roots for certain polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$. I tried to work on the case of trinomials and write every $x\in \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ in a form of $p^vu$ for $u\in (\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$, $0\leq v< k$. But then that goes into a very tedious discussion.

I am pretty sure there are some better ways to do this...

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: "certain polynomials" mind clarifying that ?

Comment: Just say any trinomial: $c_0+c_1x^{d_1}+c_2x^{d_2}$

Comment: Depends on the type of the polynomial. One of the best cases is that if the polynomial, when reduced modulo $p$ (so viewed as a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$), has only simple zeros (this is easy to check algorithmically). Then Hensel lifting kicks in, and all the mod $p$ zeros lift uniquely to a mod $p^k$ zero. If reduction mod $p$ gives something else, then it becomes a bit wild. At extremal ends you have linear polynomials like $p^{k-1}x$ with $p^{k-1}$ zeros and polynomials like $px+1$ with no zeros.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The cases I am considering now are the wild ones and assuming they have roots. For example, $h = 47^{12}+47^4x^4+x^6$ in $\mathbb{Z}/47^{13}\mathbb{Z}$ has many roots...

Comment: That's a good one! You do see that $x$ must be a multiple of $47$. So if $x=47y$, you get by plugging that in that $47^{12}+47^8y^4+47^6y^6$ must be divisible by $47^{13}$, which is equivalent to
$$47^6+47^2y^4+y^6\equiv0\pmod{47^7}.$$ Here we can repeat the dose and see that we must have $y=47z$. Plugging that in there gives an equivalent congruence
$$1+z^4+z^6\equiv0\pmod{47}.$$ That is something you can either brute force or run Berlekamp's algorithm on, and arrive at $z\in\{19,21,26,28\}\pmod {47}$. Too many ways this can branch out for me to be sure that this will always works :-(

Comment: That worked like charm for example because the highest degree term had a coefficient that was divisible by lowest power of the prime. Too late for me to think of a different scenario.